# Wordpress Erro de HTTP Upload de Imagens

Tags: wordpress

Amigos estou com um cliente que quando vai upar fotos no WP ele da esse erro

> Erro de HTTP

Já tentei o descrito neste site, mas tudo sem sucesso
http://theagoliddell.com/site/blogedicas/8-solucoes-para-o-terrivel-http-error-no-upload-do-wordpress/

Não sei mais o que fazer.

Detalhe, funcionava sem problemas antes, e sem motivos parou de funcionar.
já atualizei todos os Plugin, já atualizei o Tema, o WP está atualizado também.

> OBS Nova: Fotos com medidas abaixode 1000X700 (medida aproximada) upam sem problemas, fotos maiores o erro acontece.

Comment: já verificou as permissões da pasta uploads?

Comment: Sim, via filezzila ou pelo gerenciador do Cpanel vai sem problemas

Comment: Se as fotos pequenas funcionam o erro deve estar na hora de criar os tamanhos intermediários. O mais comum é estouro de memória, principalmente se vc estiver num servidor compartilhado, melhor ver com a sua hospedagem. Ou algum erro em código adicionado nessa etapa, filtros ou actions - mas isso é menos comum.

Comment: Não, é algum erro de Wordpress, porque eu consigo upar fotos por outros meios como falei acima, se fosse algo no server , de forma nenhuma eu conseguiria upar fotos !

Comment: Quando você faz um upload no WordPress o próprio sistema faz um monte de processamento em cada arquivo para criar os arquivos de tamanhos intermediários. Esse processamento usa bastante memória e num servidor compartilhado pequeno pode ser suficiente pra estourar a sua cota. De qualquer forma, conseguir subir arquivos pelo FTP/cpanel não é indicativo de conseguir fazer upload, visto que são usuários/processos diferentes no servidor. Se vc não incluiu código que altera esse processamento, entre em contato com a sua hospedagem que o mais provável é que o erro seja lá.